# Copying excel rows via python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

I basically have one excel file with has the following entries in a particular sheet

```
row[0][0]=hello

row[1][0]=bye

row[2][0]=hi
```

I want to copy these three rows into the number of rows present in the original sheet, so that the modified sheet has the following.

```
row[0][0]=hello

row[1][0]=bye

row[2][0]=hi

row[3][0]=hello

row[4][0]=bye

row[5][0]=hi

row[6][0]=hello

row[7][0]=bye

row[8][0]=hi
```

My code is the below.

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlrd import open_workbook
import xlwt

book=open_workbook("/Users/tusharbakaya/Desktop/test.xlsx")
book1=copy(book)
sheet=book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet1=book1.get_sheet(0)
totalrows=sheet.nrows
print totalrows
for j in range(0,totalrows):
    for i in range(0,totalrows):
        row=sheet.cell_value(i,0)
        sheet1.write(j+totalrows,0,row)
        i+=1
    j+=totalrows
book1.save("/Users/tusharbakaya/Desktop/test1.xls")
```

However, I get the following output

```
row[0][0]=hello

row[1][0]=bye

row[2][0]=hi

row[3][0]=hello

row[4][0]=hello

row[5][0]=hello

row[6][0]=hello
```

Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that even if you change the loop variable `j` inside the loop, that change would be overwritten with the next value from `range()` function.

An example to show this -

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print(i)
...     i = 1000
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

But your code is depending on this to happen, instead you should try to set to i+j*totalrows (everytime) and start j from `1`. And the logic inside the inner loop is also a bit wrong, you should depend on `i` variable as well to set the values in new workbook.

So the code would become -

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlrd import open_workbook
import xlwt

book=open_workbook("/Users/tusharbakaya/Desktop/test.xlsx")
book1=copy(book)
sheet=book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet1=book1.get_sheet(0)
totalrows=sheet.nrows
print totalrows
for j in range(0,totalrows):
    for i in range(0,totalrows):
        row=sheet.cell_value(i,0)
        sheet1.write(i+(j*totalrows),0,row)
book1.save("/Users/tusharbakaya/Desktop/test1.xls")
```

or you can use a `while` loop instead of `for` loop and

Example for while loop -

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlrd import open_workbook
import xlwt

book=open_workbook("/Users/tusharbakaya/Desktop/test.xlsx")
book1=copy(book)
sheet=book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet1=book1.get_sheet(0)
totalrows=sheet.nrows
print totalrows
j,k = 0, 0
while k < totalrows
    for i in range(0,totalrows):
        row=sheet.cell_value(i,0)
        sheet1.write(i+j,0,row)
    j+=totalrows
    k += 1
book1.save("/Users/tusharbakaya/Desktop/test1.xls")
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly :)

Thank you. Makes complete sense :)

Comment: Please do remember to accept answers for your questions (by clicking on the tick mark of the left side) if they helped you , it would help the community.

Comment: Done. Sorry, a newbie here.